# ssl address differed after SSL updated in hybrid android app

Tags: c#, android, ssl, hybrid, vitamio

I updated my hybrid android app because of the app that has 4.0.0 version of *Vitamio* can't be uploaded to google market (the android app is developed by C#, ASP.net, and window server hosting).

After update *Vitamio* from 4.0.0 to 5.0.2, Audio Streaming doesn't work.

The logcat says it has a wrong protocol address.

I'm wondering if the reason of the error is caused by updating SSL that is involved in *Vitamino*.

Here is a screenshot of the error log when streaming service starts:

[image: error log when streaming service start]

Is there any solution that I can get proper address for streaming?

Comment: Please copy the details of the error log into your question in text format, not an image

Comment: Vitamio 5.0.2 does not support mms:// anymore